# Freemarker html calendar show different icon on monday slots

Tags: html, freemarker

```
<!-- Begin Data Table -->
        <table cellspacing="0" class="collapse shadow" style="width: 100%;">
            <tbody>
   <!-- TABLE_HEADER   -->
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 14%;">Mon</th>
                    <th style="width: 14%;">Tue</th>
                    <th style="width: 14%;">Wed</th>
                    <th style="width: 14%;">Thu</th>
                    <th style="width: 14%;">Fri</th>
                </tr>
     <!-- END_TABLE_HEADER   -->
       <!--  <#list weeks as eachweek> -->
                <tr>
       <!--  <#list eachweek as eachday> -->
                    <td class="cal_day">
                        <table cellspacing="1" style="border: currentColor; width: 100%;">
                            <tbody>
    <!--  <#assign dnm=eachday.isSelectedMonth> -->
```

[Calendar View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8AD7.png)

I have a calendar in HTML which uses freemarker and I am trying to make it so there is an extra icon on Monday so that instead of just the building and the rounded icon there will also be an additional icon next to those two. I only want this icon to appear on the Monday slots however is this possible??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the header, Monday is always the first item in the 2nd `#list`, so you could write something like `<#if eachday?is_first>...<#else>...</#if>`, or `<img src="/icons/${eachday?is_first?then('monday', 'normal-day')}.png">`.

I would also recommend choosing better variable names: `<#list weeks as week>` amd `<#list week as day>`, and so you end up with `day?is_first` which is more telling.

Note that `?is_first` exists since 2.3.23 only.